# Не получается задать событие HTML body элементу

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть  HTML body после нажатия на которого хочу получить `alert()`,

```html
<div class="screen">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus incidunt enim modi soluta, quam excepturi mollitia ratione dolore iure. Esse recusandae praesentium nesciunt maxime voluptates doloremque debitis facere autem dignissimos.
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"
  integrity="sha256-fNXJFIlca05BIO2Y5zh1xrShK3ME+/lYZ0j+ChxX2DA="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  
  <script>
    $('div.screen').css('background-color', 'red');
    $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
    
    $('body').on('click', function() {
      alert('event on body is working');
    })
  </script>
```

Но получается что *event click* **работает только на красной части страницы**, то есть там где находится **div.screen**, а в остальных **зеленных частях не работает**.

*Почему click* **на зеленной части экрана** *не активизирует alert()* ?

***Если* зеленные части это не body**, почему **после назначения через jquery.css** *зеленного цвета* , ***весь экран стал зеленным*** ?

Как через **css стили** *сделать* **body во весь экран**, *чтобы событие click* работала ?

Comment: Может не на body, а на document добавлять? Например так: document.addEventListener("click", function() { alert('event on body is working'); });

Comment: Это решение но хочется понять почему , именно на body  не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/

> In the absence of a background on the html element, the body
>   background will cover the page. If there is a background on the html
>   element, the body background behaves just like any other element.

То есть

> В отсутствие фона элемента `html`, фон элемента `body` покрывает всю
>   страницу. Если у элемента `html` есть фон, то фон элемента `body`
>   ведет себя как фон любого другого элемента.

Получается, что там, где у Вас виден зеленый цвет, элемента `body` нет.

Сравним:

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.screen {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus incidunt enim modi soluta, quam excepturi mollitia ratione dolore iure. Esse recusandae praesentium nesciunt maxime voluptates doloremque debitis facere autem dignissimos.
</div>
```

```css
html {
  background-color: blue;
}

body {
  background-color: green;
}

.screen {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen">
- Where did the body go?<br/>
- It is behind me!<br/><br/>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus incidunt enim modi soluta, quam excepturi mollitia ratione dolore iure. Esse recusandae praesentium nesciunt maxime voluptates doloremque debitis facere autem dignissimos.
</div>
```